# Laravel - How to get current user in AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, service-provider

So I am usually getting the current user using `Auth::user()` and when I am determining if a user is actually logged in `Auth::check`. However this doesn't seem to work in my `AppServiceProvider`. I am using it to share data across all views. I `var_dump` both `Auth::user()` and `Auth::check()` while logged in and I get `NULL` and `false`.

How can I get the current user inside my `AppServiceProvider` ? If that isn't possible, what is the way to get data that is unique for each user (data that is different according to the `user_id`) across all views. Here is my code for clarification.

```
if (Auth::check()) {
        $cart = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        if ($cart) {
            view()->share('cart', $cart);

        }
    } else {
        view()->share('cartItems', Session::get('items'));
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a custom middleware for this, see the discussions: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-auth-in-service-provider-to-get-user-object, https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7906

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Laravel session is initialized in a middleware so you can't access the session from a Service Provider, because they execute **before** the middleware in the request lifecycle

You should use a middleware to share your varibles from the session

However, If for some other reason you want to do it in a service provider, you can do it using a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers) with a callback, like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    //compose all the views....
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
    {
        $cart = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        
        //...with this variable
        $view->with('cart', $cart );    
    });  
}
```

The callback will be executed only when the view is actually being composed, so middlewares will be already executed and session will be available

Comment: Just a note, I tried doing this today (Laravel 5.4) and it would not work with a closure as indicated in this answer. Providing a class name to an external object, e.g. `view()->composer('*', \App\Http\ViewComposers\MyComposer::class)` was the only way I could get it to recognize `Auth::user()` as anything but `null`.

Comment: how I can achieve same when using APIs as their are not blade/view used when using Laravel API's

Comment: yeah this approach worked for me

Comment: This is great It works for Laravel 9 too.

Answer (score 19):

In `AuthServiceProvider`'s `boot()` function write these lines of code

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function($view)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $view->with('currentUser', Auth::user());
        }else {
            $view->with('currentUser', null);
        }
    });
}
```

Here `*` means - in all of your views `$currentUser` variable is available.

Then, from view file `{{ currentUser }}` will give you the User info if user is authenticated otherwise null.

Comment: I want to share my cart data to all pages , it's helped me lot

Comment: Nice solution, although I'd suggest not putting in `AuthServiceProvider` as `boot()` should be limited to registering authentication and authorization services. Maybe `AppServiceProvider` or even `ComposerServiceProvider`?

Comment: how I can achieve same when using APIs as their are not blade/view used when using Laravel API's

Comment: @AbhiBurk in api, you've to definitely pass a token to get data.
I'm not sure if that can be done in AppServiceProvider.

Answer (score -1):

As per my Laravel 7 experience, `Auth::user()` does not work in `AppServiceProvider.php` instead the helper function `auth()->user()` did the trick for me.

```
public function boot()
    {

        if (auth()->check()) {
            View::composer('layout.app', function ($view) {
                $userName = auth()->user()->name;
                $view->with(['userName' => $userName]);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work in laravel 8