# Access user in AppServiceProvider?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I need to be able to pass data to all views when the user is logged in.

Here is what my `AppServiceProvider` currently looks like:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        if (Auth::check())
        {
            View::share('key', 'value');
        }
    }
}
```

However, the data is never passed to the view because I can't use `Auth` (for some reason) in `AppServiceProvider` so the if statement condition is never met.

Following a [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37373424/7971549) I found, I tried doing this:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer('*', function ($view)
        {
            if (Auth::check())
            {
                View::share('key', 'value');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked, but the problem is that the closure is called whenever a view is rendered.

For example, if my blade template includes 3 other blade templates (which it does), then the closure above will be called 4 times. [Explained further here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-auth-in-service-provider-to-get-user-object/replies/79555).

So how can I access the user correctly in `AppServiceProvider`?

Comment: It would seem when service providers are being loaded, the authentication mechanism has not been setup yet.  The only work-around that I can think of is to add a handler for the `'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login'` event which stores the key and value to session.  Then you'd just grab it out of the session in your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the `Auth` methods do not work in a direct context in the `AppSeviceProvider`, is that the Auth system is not loaded yet. In the defined closure, the Auth system will be available, as it always loaded before this closure is executed. Hence, the problem is in the way the view composer is used.

The `composer` method only accepts an array (or a string) of view identifiers and an `*`. Therefore, the following options are available:

*Define multiple views*

```
View::composer(['about', 'contact'], function ($view)
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }
}
```

*Define one view, and make this the main parent view for all the relevant pages*

You could, for example, define a `main.blade.php` and extend this view with all relevant views.

```
@extends('main')
```

And just share the `main` view:

```
View::composer('main', function ($view)
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }
}
```

There are other options available, for example filters or a parent controller. Excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608795).