# Laravel 5 want to access auth user id in model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to access the currently logged In user ID in the model. So in the model, I have written the codes;

```
namespace App\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Auth;
```

and in the method under the model, I used this code: `Auth::user()->id`
However, I receives the error:

> Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372357/laravel-how-to-get-current-user-in-appserviceprovider You can't get the auth user in service providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to check if exists an user logged, then check the id

```
  if (Auth::check()) {
  //there is a user logged in, now to get the id
     Auth::user()->id
  }
```

Comment: When I use the code in the controller it works, but not in the model.

Answer (score 2):

Auth::user() is checking web guard only. You were probably trying this with an API. This will give you the user:

```
$user = \Auth::user() ?? \Auth::guard("api")->user();
```

Comment: Thanks `Auth::guard("sanctum")` worked for me because i am using the sanctum package

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the id you must use:

```
Auth::id()
```

Other user properties are accessed like you tried

```
Auth::user()->otherProperties
```

Comment: Works on controller but not in model.

Comment: Did you implement login/register using **php artisan make:auth** ? Its weird that it's not working on model as you are using use\Auth..

Comment: If you post the Model, and the route with the controller of the model I could try to help you figure it out

Comment: I have not created the model with php artisan. The code for the model is written in my question as above.

Comment: are you using 'extends Model' on your php class?

Comment: Yes, class UserPermission extends Model

Comment: Then if you want more help please provide how you access that method 'route' and also try to debug using Auth::check()

Comment: for your current route try: Route::get('/your-route', function () {
    dd(Auth::user());
}); See if that outputs correctly

Comment: Then it probably means your log in isn't well done. if you add the files regarding that I could provide more help, eventhough as I said before with 'php artisan make:auth' laravel creates the login and registration logic for you, and if you need custom stuff you can tweak it on top of that

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara please share your all file code so we can help you. Because as per your above code it's working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

// Get the currently authenticated user...

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

// Get the currently authenticated user's ID...

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged in to get the current logged user.

Try checking for logged in user before using it

```
if (Auth::user()) {   // Check is user logged in
           // do stuff

        }
```

Comment: I dd(Auth::user()) in the model but it return null. Believe me, I've logged In.

Answer (score 0):

You can get easily logged in user id in model. Try bellow code. It's working perfect.

```
app('Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard')->user()->id;
```

Comment: No actually I called the db method from AppserviceProvider and thus it is not finding the Auth ID, Because Appserviceprovider called before auth loaded.

Comment: DB and Auth are both different. You can easily get this. I have tried and get this with use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;