# Auth::check() Returns False in Laravel Model but Returns True in Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-authentication

I have a Laravel application where I want to get `Auth::user` in my model. However, when I do `Auth::check()` in the model, it returns `false` whereas in the controller it returns `true.`

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    if (Auth::check()){ //returns false
        // do my stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `boot` function on models is executed before the `AuthProvider` is loaded. Otherwise the default auth provider couldn't be able to use the `User` model.

Because of this, you do not have access to the user details in the `boot` function.

Comment: You answer seems legit but  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50564362/laravel-5-want-to-access-auth-user-id-in-model here they are doing something similar

Comment: Yes, the function would work fine if you use it in code that you call manually when Laravel has been loaded. It just won't work in the boot function.

Comment: It also sounds like a code smell to use `Auth::check()` in a model function, to be honest. It may even prevent you from using certain functionality within console commands, for example.