# I want to share Auth::user () using View::share

Tags: laravel

Here are the sources I wrote.

app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id);
    }
}
```

The following error occurs:

> "Trying to get property 'user_id' of non-object"

When I used `Auth::user()->user_id` elsewhere, it was displayed correctly. But not here. What is the reason?

Comment: You can use Auth::id(), may be it is working fine for older version of laravel

Answer (score 1):

Does your users table have column named "user_id" or you mean users table "id" column? if you mean users table id column update your code to below.

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'user_id' is my newly created column. Furthermore, If I use `Auth::user()->id`, I will get an error of "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object".

Comment: Check if you are getting the Auth object try this code add "use Auth" before the class begins and inside boot() write dd(Auth::User()); check if this is returned.

Comment: I tried `dd(Auth::User ());`. The result is "null". However, some model pages output correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason through the link below.

[Laravel - How to get current user in AppServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372357/laravel-how-to-get-current-user-in-appserviceprovider)

I modified the source as below and it worked.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view)
        {
            View::share('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id);
        }
    }
}
```