# Is there a way to access current (loggedin) user within service providers boot method (in stateless api mode)?

Tags: laravel

I am defining Gates within service provider. Like this:

```
        $permissions = \DB::table('permissions')->whereNotNull('route_name')->get();
        foreach ( $permissions as $permission) {
            Gate::define($permission->route_name, function($user) use ($permission){
                return $user->hasPermission($permission->route_name);
            });
        };
```

I am able to access the current user within the callback of the Gate but I cant acces the user outside the callback. Instead that above I want define the gates directly like:

```
        $permissions = \Auth::user()->permissions();
        foreach ( $permissions as $permission) {
            Gate::define($permission->route_name, function($user) {
                return true;
            });
        };
```

Is that possible ?

PS: I can't access `auth()->user()` like in some similar questions because I am using stateless authentication without session.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/37373424/1978311

Comment: @KurtFriars No I already tried those. But they don't work if you don't use session. I use stateless authentication without session so it does not work.

Comment: A yes, I see. I will think more about it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Gate::define` is a callback method. The gates are defined in boot stage. They don't run at the time they are defined in boot stage, but only made ready to run in runtime. In the boot stage most of services (including auth) are not loaded yet.

So it is not possible to access the (logged) user at this time.