# problem to access authenticate user in register app service provider

Tags: laravel

I have a problem to access Authenticate user in app service provider, here is my code. In cart Class (it's a custom class), I don't have access to current User.
How can I access to Current user in custom Class?

```
public function register()
{
   $this->app->singleton(Cart::class,function($app) {
       return new Cart($app->auth->user());
   });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... if you try to resolve this `Cart` class before the `StartSession` middleware runs you will not have access to the 'session' which is what the default authentication system uses for authentication. also you probably want `$app->auth->user()` or `$app['auth']->user()` as there is not an `auth` method on `Application`

Comment: A similar question has already been answered. This may help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37373424/10602851