# Where to switch to other service depending on logged user field?

Tags: laravel, laravel-service-container

In laravel 9 app I try to switch to different service

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if ($this->app->environment('local')) {
            $this->app->register(\Laravel\Telescope\TelescopeServiceProvider::class);
            $this->app->register(TelescopeServiceProvider::class);

            $this->app->register(\Barryvdh\LaravelIdeHelper\IdeHelperServiceProvider::class);
        }
        
        // Error pointing at this line
        $loggedUser  = Auth::user();


        if( $loggedUser->membership_mark === 'G') { // G=>Gold Membership
            $this->app->bind('App\Interfaces\PageMembershipMarkStrategyInterface',
                'App\Implementations\PageGoldMemberStrategy');

        }
    }
```

But I got error :

```
 Target class [hash] does not exist. in...
```

Looks like register method is not proper place for  app->bind when I need to get logged user.
But where have I to make this binding? In custom service provider? Im middleware ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
I create a middleware with command  :

```
php artisan make:middleware SetPageMembershipMarkService
```

and in app/Http/Kernel.php I added it :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,

    // I added this line : 
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetPageMembershipMarkService::class,

    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
```

But I got error :

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [App\Interfaces\PageMembershipMarkStrategyInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\InformOnPageInStockController]....
```

I am not sure in which place of Kernel.php I have to add ref to PageMembershipMarkStrategyInterface ?
checking log it appears that my SetPageMembershipMarkService is not triggered before error...

**MODIFIED BLOCK 2:**

In file app/Http/Kernel.php I added my Middleware reference:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,

    // I set it AFTER auth
    'setPageMembership' =>\App\Http\Middleware\SetPageMembershipMarkService::class,

    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminat`enter code here`e\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

abd in routes/api.php :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->prefix('v1') /*->name('api.v1')*/ ->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    ...
    
    Route::middleware(['setPageMembership'])->group(function () {
        Route::resource('/inform-on-page-in-stock', InformOnPageInStockController::class)->except(['edit', 'add']);
   });
```

and I still got error :

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [App\Interfaces\InformOnPageInStockStrategyInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\InformOnPageInStockController].
```

1. Checking logs I do not find log message I set in SetPageMembershipMarkService middleware, so looks like it does
   not set before my controllers...
   What is wrong ?
2. You mentioned using of RouteServiceProvider. Which is correct syntax ?

File **app/Http/Middleware/SetPageMembershipMarkService.php** has lines :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class SetPageMembershipMarkService
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $loggedUser  = Auth::user();
        \Log::info(varDump($loggedUser, ' -1 SetPageMembershipMarkService $loggedUser::'));

        $membershipMark = $loggedUser->membership_mark;

        if( $membershipMark === 'S') { // G=>Silver Membership
            app()->bind('App\Interfaces\InformOnPageInStockStrategyInterface',
                'App\Implementations\HasNoInformOnPageInStockStrategy');
        }

        if( $membershipMark === 'G') { // G=>Gold Membership
            app()->bind('App\Interfaces\InformOnPageInStockStrategyInterface',
                'App\Implementations\InformOnPageInStockGoldMembersStrategy');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But in log file I do not see any log message I have in this Middleware...

Thanks!

Comment: Add your middleware code here too. This error comes when the interface was not binded to the class.

Comment: I added content of app/Http/Middleware/SetPageMembershipMarkService.php middleware

Comment: run `php artisan route:clear`, and try once again and try to use `dd`  the auth user data this time on the top of the handle method to check if it is running.

Comment: I run command I run php artisan route:clear and I still got error :

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Target [App\Interfaces\InformOnPageInStockStrategyInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\InformOnPageInStockController]. 

Also I run all possible clear commands :

php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled

composer dump-autoload


But I still got the same error!

Comment: Are there some online manuals on this issue? I searched and drowned...

Comment: Have you implemented the InformOnPageInStockStrategyInterface in both of the dependency? Also, the doing as shown in the comment of this article also works to get auth data in AppServiceProvider https://dev.to/kyam/laravel-how-to-bind-an-interface-based-on-request-parameters-dp5 thi

Comment: Thanks for this link, but in it I did not find where middleware is registered. In  app/Http/Kernel.php or in some other place. That seems the key issue.

Comment: [Assigning Middleware To Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes) Laravel middleware can only be registered in the Http/Kernel.php not in Console/Kernel.php. Also if you follow the this [comment](https://dev.to/kyam/laravel-how-to-bind-an-interface-based-on-request-parameters-dp5#comment-1i27l) from above you don't need to use middleware and AppServiceProvider will be able to handle the bind.

Comment: This example seems not good. What is “request()->user_name ” ?
It does not look like authorozed user.
I need to get logged user from Auth::user()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to get `Auth:user()` data in Service Provder. Because service provider runs before Laravel sets the `Auth` data, you'll have to use some hacky methods to handle it.

I think better ways to handle data related to `auth` would be on middleware and not in Service Provider.

Additional explanations can be found on this questions answer [Laravel - How to get current user in AppServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372357/laravel-how-to-get-current-user-in-appserviceprovider)

**EDIT** for modifed block

Your middleware registration is wrong.

`$routeMiddleware` this array is used to register a custom middleware which you gonna use and define manually

For example:

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    .....
    // I added this line : 
    'setPageMembership' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetPageMembershipMarkService::class,
```

Then you gonna use this middleware in your route groups like:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'setPageMembership'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('test', [TestController::class, 'test']);
});
```

If you want the middleware to run for all the routes it is better to add it in the `$middleware` array or if you want in the certain route group (web/api) then in the `$middlewareGroups` individual `web` and `api` array.

Adding the middleware in RouteServiceProvder also works if you want every route to have the middleware.

However, for your use case, authentication is required before binding. So, you will need `auth` middleware to fire first before you perform those bind actions. So adding the middleware to your route file like I showed above will be enough for your use case.

Comment: Please add MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: @mstdmstd edited. Check it our.

Comment: Please  MODIFIED BLOCK # 2