# Why view()->composer( in AppServiceProvider is not triggered?

Tags: laravel

On laravel 9 site I need to get the current user in AppServiceProvider.

I know that usually current user is not available in AppServiceProvider.

I found this branch
[Laravel - How to get current user in AppServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372357/laravel-how-to-get-current-user-in-appserviceprovider)
it propose      a way like :

```
...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

public function register()
{
    //compose all the views....
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
    {
            \Log::info('View in register ');    
    });  
}


public function boot()
{
    //compose all the views....
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) 
    {
            \Log::info('View in boot ');    
    });  
}
```

But none of the events is triggered and I do not see any log messages.
Actually that is API project with passport and it does not use views...
Do I see set additive options/packages/etc ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.26.1",
"laravel/passport": "^10.4.1",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if there are no views being rendered then there are no views to compose .... the next thing is why do you need access to the current user in a service provider?

Comment: I need to switch to different class  implementation depending of field of logged user. Usually that is done in a service provider

Comment: If there to add fake views to compose ? Or are there better way for this task?

Comment: view composers are for sharing data with a view, that is all they are for ... you can bind things to the container at any time

Comment: @lagbox, "you can bind things to the container at any time " - Do you mean that I can do it in some other way ? Please, detalize...